# Seeking advice on optimizing synchronous loop performance with asyncio and telethon in Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

When running my code I realized that after around 30 requests it gets very slow to fetch the rest, taking a long time to complete the code.

My goal with this code is to fetch users from a Telegram's group and dump their information in a JSON file, with ther name, username and bio.

This is the code I am running:

```
import configparser
import json
import asyncio

from telethon.tl.functions.users import GetFullUserRequest 
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.errors import SessionPasswordNeededError
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch
from telethon.tl.types import (
    PeerChannel
)

# Reading Configs
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

# Setting configuration values
api_id = config['Telegram']['api_id']
api_hash = config['Telegram']['api_hash']

api_hash = str(api_hash)

phone = config['Telegram']['phone']
username = config['Telegram']['username']

# Create the client and connect
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)

async def main(phone):
    await client.start()
    print("Client Created")

    # Ensure you're authorized
    if await client.is_user_authorized() == False:
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        try:
            await client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            await client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))

    me = await client.get_me()

    user_input_channel = input("enter entity(telegram URL or entity id):")

    if user_input_channel.isdigit():
        entity = PeerChannel(int(user_input_channel))
    else:
        entity = user_input_channel

    my_channel = await client.get_entity(entity)

    offset = 0
    limit = 100
    all_participants = []
    count = 0

    while True:
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(my_channel, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit,hash=0))
        if not participants.users or offset >= 100:
            break
        all_participants.extend(participants.users)
        count +=1
        print(len(participants.users))
        offset += len(participants.users)
        print("finished")

    all_user_details = []
    for participant in all_participants:
        user_full = await client(GetFullUserRequest(participant.id))
        all_user_details.append({
            "id": user_full.full_user.id,
            "bio": user_full.full_user.about
        })

    with open('user_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(all_user_details, outfile)

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main(phone))
```

With some debug I could realize that the problem is the in the for loop, this is the loop it is taking a long time to complete

```
for participant in all_participants:
        user_full = await client(GetFullUserRequest(participant.id))
        all_user_details.append({
            "id": user_full.full_user.id,
            "bio": user_full.full_user.about
        })
```

Why is this happening and how do I optmize this code to run more effiently?

My compiler is python3 version 3.11.6

Do you guys need more information?

**Update----------------**

What I have tried:

As [jsbueno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/108205/jsbueno) suggested, I've adjusted my code to send multiple requests instead of one request by user, using the asyncio. It worked well for a group base with 80 users, but above from that, I got the following errors:

1. `Server response had invalid buffer: Invalid response buffer (HTTP code 429)`
2. `Server indicated flood error at transport level: Invalid response buffer (HTTP code 429)`

which indicates too many concurrent requests to the API, so I have tried with the semaphore method, and ended up with the code like this:

```
# ... (other imports and code)
api_semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(10) #Updated line

async def main(phone):
    await client.start()
    print("Client Created")
    # Ensure you're authorized
    if await client.is_user_authorized() == False:
        await client.send_code_request(phone)
        try:
            await client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
        except SessionPasswordNeededError:
            await client.sign_in(password=input('Password: '))

    me = await client.get_me()

    user_input_channel = input("enter entity(telegram URL or entity id):")

    if user_input_channel.isdigit():
        entity = PeerChannel(int(user_input_channel))
    else:
        entity = user_input_channel

    my_channel = await client.get_entity(entity)

   # Fetch all participants
    offset = 0
    limit = 100
    all_participants = []
    count = 0

    while True:
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(my_channel, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit,hash=0))
        if not participants.users or offset >= 1000:
            break
        all_participants.extend(participants.users)
        count +=1
        print(len(participants.users))
        offset += len(participants.users)
        print("finished")

    # Process the participants as needed
    all_user_details = []
    tasks = []
    for participant in all_participants:
        async with api_semaphore:
            # This will prepare all requests and let them be ready to go
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(client(GetFullUserRequest(participant.id)))) #Updated line 
# ... (rest of the code)
```

With that code, I still have the same problems mentioned earlier, even though they are limited in concurrent requests now. Why is this happening, and what is taking so much time of processing after the loops are finished?

Answer (score 2):

Although you are usign asynchronous libs, you are making all your requests for participants in series - meaning for 30 uers, you make 30 requests, one just after the previous other was finished.

One can easily do this concurrently with asyncio code - for example, you can rewrite this part of your code:

```
...
async def main():
    ...
    all_user_details = []
    for participant in all_participants:
        user_full = await client(GetFullUserRequest(participant.id))
        all_user_details.append({
            "id": user_full.full_user.id,
            "bio": user_full.full_user.about
        })
...
```

more or less like this:

```
from asyncio import Semaphore


async def main():
    ...
    
    tasks = []
    for participant in all_participants:
        # This will prepare all requests and let then ready to go;
        # but without the "await", they won't be triggered one by one.
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(client(GetFullUserRequest(participant.id))))
        
    # this will launch all the requests in parallel and gather the results:
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    all_user_details = [{"id": user_full.full_user.id, "bio": user_full.full_user.about} for user_full in results]
```

Now, depending on the number of users and on your network, sending all requests "at once" (not really "at once" but they are sent as fast as possible), may cause some failures. If that is the case, you will have to create some more code and make use of an `asyncio.Semaphore`  or other strategy to limit the number of concurrent requests to the API.

Comment: very interesting, I understood the problem then. I'll try to make these adjustments and update this post. Thank your very much!

Comment: I have tried what you told me, and according to the debug I did, the for loop definitely finished way faster, like instantly. But why does it still take a long time to finish after the loop? It took 1 minute and 7 seconds

Comment: Obs: The telegram channel I am trying to fetch has 80 users. When I Try to fetch another channel with 1000 users, I get errors, like 429 HTTP, invalid response buffer. I think it falls into the situation you described earlier, which I'll try to solve with semaphore.